# How to get a better square wave out of ne555

Tags: 555

I built a basic astable circuit for the 555 and I'm using an oscilloscope to view the output.

I know this IC is supposed to output a square wave but instead I get these slopes (I don't know what to call them) in the wave. Is there a way I can get better waveforms out of the circuits like putting more capacitors or others?

[image]

[image: with ac coupled you mean that switch?]

[image: this is the calibration signal from the scope, this has a more square shape]

Comment: What is the load, what is your exact circuit, how have you configured the scope (AC coupled?) have you tuned the scopeprobe

Comment: If you're just putting a scope probe on pin 3 of the 555 and there's no load, the scope is probably AC coupled.  If that's not the case, then post your schematic, and post a picture of the control panel of your scope.

Comment: Your scope is AC coupled. Put it in DC mode.

Comment: @NicoPerez now that your question is answered, this would be an **excellent** chance to write your first answer – to your own post! That way, the question can be marked as "solved", and future people with the same problem see prominently how to solve it. A single sentence answer suffices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scope was AC coupled. I changed it to DC and I got an almost perfect squarewave.